# Extracting by position working differently in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, vector, overlapping-features, qgis-modeler, extract

I am trying to create a tool in the QGIS modeler. The idea is to select lines within an area by hand (e.g. select features by polygon) and the first step of the tool would be to select/extract all parcels (polygons) crossed by lines.

However, as you can see from the screenshot, there is no way to *"ignore invalid geometry"* for selected lines in the modeler tool.

[image]

In comparison, this is what the "regular" tool looks like, and it has the wrench symbol to let me change the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For QGIS 3.32 and above.

When you *run* the model, you can click the "Advanced" button and change the default invalid feature filtering behaviour.

[image]

Comment: "Algorithm Settings..." is not listed for me. Do I have to activiate that somewhere?

Comment: It's only available when  running the model, not when opening the tool while editing the model.

Comment: I tried it when running the model, does not show. What version of QGIS are you using? I'm on 3.30

Comment: Using version 3.32

Comment: Trying to fix that with an update - this feature is however not listed in the documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html#other-tools)

Comment: Updating QGIS to 3.32 gave me that option. It's not the most beatiful way, since I would rather include that inside the model, but I will take it for now

Answer (score 3):

You could place an algorithm in front of extracting, which a) fix invalid Geometries or b) remove them.

Another option would be to trigger all these algorithms with PyQGIS, then you will have the same parameters as when you run manually.

Comment: Yes I know, but we actually "need" the objects even with the invalid geometries. They are created by a third party program to be used in AutoCAD

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found the best solution for now. It is possible to change the preset of algorithms to ignore invalid geometries.

Settings > Processing > General > filter invalid objects > Ignore objects with invalid geometry

But I recommend to be cautios with that change, it might mess with some plugins and you should know your data well.